# How to round down to half value

Tags: c#, rounding

I'm trying to round like follows.

```
1.1 -> 1
1.2 -> 1
.
1.4 -> 1
1.5 -> 1.5
1.6 -> 1.5
.
.
1.9 -> 1.5
2 -> 2
```

How can i achieve this? I tried **Math.Round(value)**, **Math.Round(value, 1)**, **Math.Round(value,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)** Nothing seem to achieve what i need. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Try `Math.Floor(value * 2) / 2`

Comment: @maccettura That question is slightly different as it has 1.3 and 1.4 rounding to 1.5 but here the OP wants those to go to 1.

Comment: Try to add 0.5, round to integer and subtract 0.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can try:

```
decimal HalfRound(decimal value)
{
    var floor = Math.Floor(value);

    return floor += (value - floor) < 0.5M ? 0.0M : 0.5M;
}
```

Lets test above function for some of OP's data:

```
Console.WriteLine($"1.1 => {HalfRound(1.1M)}");
Console.WriteLine($"1.2 => {HalfRound(1.2M)}");
Console.WriteLine($"1.4 => {HalfRound(1.4M)}");
Console.WriteLine($"1.5 => {HalfRound(1.5M)}");
Console.WriteLine($"1.6 => {HalfRound(1.6M)}");
Console.WriteLine($"1.9 => {HalfRound(1.9M)}");
Console.WriteLine($"2.0 => {HalfRound(2.0M)}");
Console.WriteLine($"3.5 => {HalfRound(3.5M)}");
Console.WriteLine($"3.6 => {HalfRound(3.6M)}");
Console.WriteLine($"3.9 => {HalfRound(3.9M)}");
```

**Result:**

```
//1.1 => 1.0
//1.2 => 1.0
//1.4 => 1.0
//1.5 => 1.5
//1.6 => 1.5
//1.9 => 1.5
//2.0 => 2.0
//3.5 => 3.5
//3.6 => 3.5
//3.9 => 3.5
```